# Product of gradients of 2 perpendicular lines

Tags: calculus

We know that the product of the gradients of two perpendicular lines is -1. How is that when we take the gradient of the y axis(infinity) and the x axis(0) we don't get -1?

Comment: "We know that the product of the gradients of two perpendicular lines is -1."  There's your error- we DON'T know that.  What we know is that "if two perpendicular lines have FINITE slope then the product of their slopes is -1.  That statement does not even make sense if one of the lines does not have a slope (does not have a finite slope)..

Answer (score 1):

The result follows from the fact that (considering two perpendicular lines are $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians apart) $$\tan\theta \cdot \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \theta \right) = \tan\theta \cdot (-\cot\theta) =  -1$$

When considering the $x$ and $y$ axes, the product of both gradients would correspond to the case when $\theta = 0$, in which case $\tan \frac{\pi}{2}$ is undefined.

Indeed, the result does not hold for all perpendicular lines.